# Error: This content can't be shown in a Frame?

Tags: error, page-viewer-web-part

I used pageviewer webpart. When I try clicking on the video link, I get this error: 
This content can’t be shown in a frame
There is supposed to be some content here, but the publisher doesn’t allow it to be displayed in a frame. This is to help protect the security of any information you might enter into this site.

How do I fix this?

The code I have is this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The owner of the "framed" content has added JavaScript to detect it is being loaded in a frame. You may need to add a link that when clicked opens their content in a new window or tab. They probably have some code like this in their page:

```
if (window.self !== window.top) {   error messages here   }
```

Comment: I have added the code to the questions. Do you think it is because of the code I have attached?

Answer (score 0):

You need to **Permit iframes from any external domain into pages** on this site as the following:

- Go to Site Collection Settings > Site Collection Administration > HTML Field Security
- Check `Permit contributors to insert iframes from any external domain into pages on this site.`

[image]

- Go back to your page and check if the Page URL has been rendered inside the Page Viewer web part or not!

> **Note:** If the issue still persists that means **the publisher of this
>   content does not allow it to be displayed in a frame.**

Comment: I don't see site collection admin. I don't have the right privileges for it. Is there any other way to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a pop up window to see the video :) in that way it does not follow the resctrictions from sharepoint. It use basic html javascript basis :)

Comment: I have a video slider, would the pop up work for that too